# OpenCV Drawing Contour Error Assertion Failed

Tags: python, opencv, contour

So I am trying to follow guide on how to scan a document in https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/
exactly on the step 2 process where i am supposed to find the contour and draw it to the image, i got an "Assertion Failed" error on drawContour function

The guide did not have

> screenCnt = None

so at first i got Error like screenCnt did not exist

after i add it, got Assertion Failed instead
even though i used the same image as the guide and tried another image too

```
#find contour
cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:5]
screenCnt = None

# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
        screenCnt = approx
        break

#draw contour
cv2.drawContours(image, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

Here is what i got :

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/learn/project/app.py", line 218, in
>    cv2.drawContours(image, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
>
> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2606:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) reader.ptr != NULL in function
>   'cvDrawContours'

Any solution for this ? Thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `screenCnt = 0` instead of `None`. and let me know.
For your reference, I'm providing small code snippet:

```
(cnts, contours, heirarchy) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), 
cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cnts = contours[0]
screenCnt = 0

for contour in contours:
    # get rectangle bounding contour
    [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

# draw rectangle around contour on original image
#cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,255),2)

##### code added..for thresholding
for c in cnts:
    # approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)

    # if our approximated contour has four points, then
    # we can assume that we have found our screen
    if len(approx) == 4:
        screenCnt = approx
        break
```

Comment: is x,y,w,h part of contour variable ? I got an error because of those

Comment: No that's the commented part.

Comment: Thanks i tried part of your code and some other guides, now i can put contour as i like. Anyway do you work in AI related topics ? I saw your profile as an AI Engineer

Comment: Yes I'm AI Engineer since 4yrs

Answer (score 0):

Try printing all the inputs to the function that you are providing. I guess you may find something wrong. 
Let me know in the comments below.

Comment: it seems that the length of approx never reach 4
as i tried to print the approx i got this
[[[ 87 452]]]
[[[ 88 451]]]
[[[ 90 453]]]
[[[ 90 455]]]
[[[ 91 456]]]

Comment: That is where the problem is. Try removing if condition and limit the size of screenCnt to 4.

Comment: Basically you are fitting a polynomial around your image. So when you don't provide a point to draw contrours it says null pointer exception. To resolve the error you can provide dummy points (4 points) in screenCNT and it will get resolved. I think you can take on from here:)

Comment: i am still quite confused, if i provide dummy points, how can the function draw the rectangle correctly around the images ? Sorry if i can't catch on fast, it's my first time with Python